# Nextflow examples don't show expected output

Tags: nextflow

This example is from the nextflow [docs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-type-val)

```
process basicExample {
  input:
  val x

  "echo process job $x"
}

workflow {
  def num = Channel.of(1,2,3)
  basicExample(num)
}
```

It says output should be similar to:

```
process job 3
process job 1
process job 2
```

However, I only see one of these outputs.  For example: `process job 2` when I look in `.command.out`.  Note, that there is only one folder in db/9217e2 folder with one `.command.out` file.

```
$> find  "work/db/"  -name ".command.out"                                                                                                                      
work/db/9217e2451637514ea8ab5791fbcca4/.command.out
```

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.10.0
Launching `../../nextflow/channelexample.nf` [festering_stonebraker] DSL2 - revision: 110bfce0a9
executor >  local (3)
[db/9217e2] process > basicExample (3) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
```

Answer (score 0):

Nextflow defaults to iterating each process over a list of inputs. So each process will only have 1 output, and your input will be in a random order.

If you want to use all inputs in one process it would be something like this:

```
process basicExample {
  input:
  val x

  script:
  def echo_all = x.collect{ "echo process job $it" }.join('\n')
  """
  ${echo_all}
  """  

}

workflow {
  def num = Channel.of(1,2,3).collect()
  basicExample(num)
}
```

And another way to better monitor your jobs if you're iterating over a list is to use `tag`.

```
process basicExample {
  tag "$x"

  input:
  val x

  "echo process job $x"
}
```

This will then put your output to something like this, where x is the value of $x the process is using:

```
[81/a571ca] process > basicExample (x) [0%] 0 of 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `.command.out` in one work directory. Nextflow made 3 seperate directories inside the work directory, one for each instance of the `basicExample` process that was called. If you look in the other workfolders, you will see the other outputs.

Comment: I thought so, too. But that is not what I see.  I updated the post to show there are not three `.command.out` files

Comment: Do a `ls -a work/*/*/.command.out`  and you will see there are 3 files each in their own `work/xx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/`  directory corresponding to process 1, 2, and 3. The other 2 just aren't in the `work/db` subdirectory.